# How to log class.method name using serilog

Tags: serilog

First I've come across some older posts suggesting workarounds for this issue.
I'm trying to get started with Serilog, but I'm having trouble getting it to log the simple things I need, similar to how I've been doing it with NLog. In NLog, I typically just add the following line at the top of the class:
private static readonly NLog.Logger Logger = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
I haven't encountered any performance problems in my programs.

The information I want to log is quite basic – essentially the minimum that everybody logs:

Time
Log level
Class name
Method name
Log message
However, with Serilog, I can't get it to include the class and method names in the logs.

I'm wondering if this feature has been built into Serilog by now. If not, what is the correct way to achieve this functionality?
(Thim must be so basic, but for some reason I can't find it in the documentation)

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Did you google? https://github.com/serilog/serilog/issues/1084 aside from the myriad of other github gists and so questions.

also - remember serilog is a structured logger, in other words is you log actions and data that would clarify your log lines when inspecting them. I've been working without this for 3ish years and i don't miss it.

Comment: Hi @sommen, Yes, I have Googled it and even tried to find a solution myself. I'm working on a fairly large solution, and it helps me to know where the log event originated. Even if not everyone uses it, I had thought that it would now be possible to include it by adding it to the log layout configuration.

Comment: Did you find a suitable way to do this? I find it very surprising that Serilog doesn't provide anything for this out of the box...